# How do I make my Discord.JS bot react to it's own Direct Message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When I'm making my bot, I want to make it so that when you type `afv!support` it will send a DM like this:
[DM example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xeVz.png)

```
Thanks for contacting AFV support. Please react below for which problem you have.
:one: Ban Appeal
:two: Bug Report
:three: Report Staff/User

This command will expire in two minutes.
```

and then react with :one:, :two:, and :three:. I've looked around but haven't found the answer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a message to your target, then resolve the promise. The promise returns the sent message.

```js
// then/catch
message.member.send(...).then(msg => {
   msg.react('<emoji>')
   msg.react('<emoji>')
   msg.react('<emoji>')
})

// async/await
const msg = await message.member.send(...);
await msg.react(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Elitezen's answer is correct, I just wanted to elaborate on their use of `<emote>`.

If you replace the first usage of `<emote>` with `:one:`, for example, it will not work correctly. You will have to enter the physical `unicode` emoji, or emoji `ID` if it's a custom emoji.

For example:

```js
message.member.send(<theMessage>).then(msg => {
   await msg.react('1️⃣') // instead of :one:
   await msg.react('2️⃣') // instead of :two:
   msg.react('3️⃣') // instead of :three:
})
```

---

Read this [`discord.js` guide on reactions for more information](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages)

Comment: Ok, just making sure 