# How to react on a specific message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey I have an Embed and I want that my Bot reacts with a Custom Emoji to it, but when I try it with my example of Code The bBot will react to every message that is send. Here's my Code:

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "set")) {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('React to gain acess to the Role "Test"')
    .setAuthor('Name')
    .setThumbnail('123')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Name');
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    if (message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)) {
        message.react('123')
    }
    }


})
```

The last part is very confusing I know but I tried everything, even this :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my Discord.JS bot react to it's own Direct Message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439272/how-do-i-make-my-discord-js-bot-react-to-its-own-direct-message)

Answer (score 0):

There is something that you should note. When you are attempting to react, you don't define a message. This will give you an error because the bot's trying to react to a message that doesn't exist (To the bot) and isn't defined. I've added some code below that takes the sent message and reacts on it

```js
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
.then(m => m.react('123'));
```

This method takes the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) given from the sent message and reacts to said message